# How to use your own video for edgetpu_demo on the coral dev board?

Tags: google-coral

For [this demo](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/#5-run-our-demo-app), it looks like you have a [--source](https://coral.googlesource.com/edgetpudemo/+/a2acb17cc944667882faafaaf1b3f372003b07fe/edgetpu_demo#14) option to change it to the video source I want. However, I've been trying with no luck to use my own video but the output images always come out as a black screen. There are also no documentations on how to format the videos, have any one here sucessfully use their own videos with this demo?

Answer (score 0):

We didn't document the video format for edgetpu_demo since it wasn't designed for changing videos. However, here is the command to format the video (you'll need to install ffmpeg):

```
$ ffmpeg -i your_video.mp4 -an -vf "scale=960:540,format=yuv420p" -colorspace bt470bg -color_range tv -color_primaries smpte170m -color_trc bt709 -vcodec libx264 -brand mp42 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline video_stream.mp4
```